# How should I thank this person who wrote a letter of rec for me (but to a different school than the one I'm attending?)

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette, recommendation-letter

I've poked around the answers here and I think my situation is unusual enough to warrant a new question. In short, I applied to graduate programs for this fall, and I did the rounds asking my professors to write letters for me. Four of them agreed, and I ended up dividing them amongst the schools that I had selected. The thing is, though, that each professor thought I was applying only to the schools that they were writing letters for.

Fast-forward past application season. I get into my schools and pick one, and I've written thank-you letters already to the three who wrote letters for my chosen school. That leaves the fourth professor, though, who might be confused (or worse, offended!) that I will end up attending a school that he knew absolutely nothing about. How should I handle this situation? I guess I could just say a generic "thanks for writing letters", but a natural segue from that is "and I got into X school", which is the awkward bit here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Directly, as if they were an actual human being.**

"Thank you for providing letters of recommendation for my graduate school applications.  I will be joining the musicology PhD program at the University of Southern North Dakota at Hoople next fall.  Although I did not need your letter for my USNDH application, I still very much appreciate your support through the application process."

Comment: I'll add two words to this excellent letter:  appreciate your support and encouragement etc.

Comment: You mean professors are people, too?! And here I thought they were grown on [Apple Island](http://www.amazon.com/Apple-Island-Truth-about-Teachers/dp/1886910251)...

Comment: Glibness aside, this is a very useful answer. Thanks!